# Ti84 Plus "$a+bi$" mode not working

Tags: complex-numbers, calculator

I just bought a new Ti84 plus when I click on mode and change "Real" to "$a+bi$" it doesn't seem to convert square root of a negative number to the complex form. I have tried it numerous times I have no idea what to do :(

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t think this is the right place to ask your question. Since you just bought it, I’d recommend referring to the user manual to understand how to engage and properly utilize each mode available to the calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to "convert" the square root of a negative number in terms of $i$ on a calculator? In my honest opinion, calculating the square root of a negative number in your head is better than on a calculator.

For instance, with $\sqrt{-576}$, you can input $\sqrt{576}$ into your calculator, and it will output $24$. You know $\sqrt {-1}$ as $i$, your answer would be $24i$.

I realize this isn't an answer to your question, it is just a recommendation to do a more efficient method.

Comment: Except this doesn’t handle the fact that the square root is multi-valued.